# highcharts dynamic data populate in line chart

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, dynamic, highcharts

I'm using highcharts and when i populate the data dynamically, its not showing up. Here's my code:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

..

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var options = {
        chart:{
            type:'line'
        },
        title:{
            text:'Line Chart'
        },
        xAxis:{
            title:'Date',
            categories:[]
        },
        yAxis:{
            title:'Val1/Val2'
        },
        series:[{name:'Val1', data:[]}, {name:'Val2', data:[]}]
    };

    $.ajax({
        url:'includes/getData.php', // select * from 'myTable' order by date
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                options.xAxis.categories.push(value.date); // date = 'mm/dd'
                options.series[0].data.push(value.val1); // val1 = integer
                options.series[1].data.push(value.val2); // val2 = integer
            });

            $('#chart').highcharts(options);
        }
    });

});
```

The categories show up just fine on the x-axis (the dates), but nothing else shows up. If I hard code the data like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var options = {
        chart:{
            type:'line'
        },
        title:{
            text:'Line Chart'
        },
        xAxis:{
            title:'Date',
            categories:['08/16','08/17','08/18','08/19']
        },
        yAxis:{
            title:'Val1/Val2'
        },
        series:[{name:'Val1', data:[23, 56, 73, 12]}, {name:'Val2', data:[12, 65, 23, 49]}]
    };

    $.ajax({
        url:'includes/getData.php', // select * from 'myTable' order by date
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                //options.xAxis.categories.push(value.date); // date = 'mm/dd'
                //options.series[0].data.push(value.val1); // val1 = integer
                //options.series[1].data.push(value.val2); // val2 = integer
            });

            $('#chart').highcharts(options);
        }
    });

});
```

it works perfectly. Notice i hardcoded the xaxis category array and the 2 series data arrays, and commented out the 3 lines in the ajax success handler where it populates using the data from the DB.

Not sure why it works hardcoded by not dynamically. I outputted the data arrays to the console in the success handler and the data is there, as expected.

Any thoughts whats wrong with this?

EDIT: JSON returned by getData:

```
 0: {0:8, 1:120, 2:80, 3:08/06/2013, 4:1:00 am, id:8, val1:120, val2:80, date:08/06/2013, time:1:00 am}
 1: {0:5, 1:120, 2:80, 3:08/08/2013, 4:3:55 am, id:5, val1:120, val2:80, date:08/08/2013, time:3:55 am}
 2: {0:9, 1:120, 2:80, 3:08/10/2013, 4:2:00 am, id:9, val1:120, val2:80, date:08/10/2013, time:2:00 am}
 3: {0:13, 1:120, 2:80, 3:08/19/2013, 4:12:00 am, id:9, val1:120, val2:80, date:08/10/2013, time:2:00 am}
```

Comment: Can you show the json that is returned by GetData?

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Are you certain val1/val2 are integers?

Comment: @Barbara - Not sure how to get the raw JSON thats returned by GetData, but i simply sent the data variable to the console in the success handler, and it outputted an array of 4 objects, each representing a record in my DB. Each object has the proper data associated with it.

Comment: @Mark - These values are inserted from a textbox within a form, so its possible they are 'strings' at that point. However the DB fields they are stored in are typed to int(11), so Im assuming they are converted to ints, if needed, when being inserted. I am doing nothing to explicitly convert them to strings. Would you suggest explicitly casting them as int's when they are returned, before inserting into the highchart series?

Comment: @blkhwks19, you can try doing a `parseInt(value.val1)` but it sounds like you are already doing it correctly.  You got me stumped!

Comment: I don't know which browser you use, but in Chrome click on the Network tab of Developer tools and you can see the response for each of your requests.  In Safari, it's the timelines.  In Firefox, it's Net and then XHR.  That can show you the exact JSON you're getting back for your GetData request.

Comment: @Barbara - Using Chrome. I edited my question to include the data returned. Not sure why it has the values listed twice, once with property names and once with numbers (0-4). But noticed even though the date and time vars are stored as simple strings (varchar) in the DB, they dont come back quoted... Im not using the time var right now, but i AM using the date var, its getting inserted into the cateogires array for the xaxis of the chart, and those show up so im thinking those are OK and not an issue, though not really sure why i cant see any of the integers as points on the chart....

Comment: Well it looks like json in incorrect, morever dates should be timestamps. In success please use stringify() and paste.

Comment: Well the user inputs a date and i convert it to a simple string ("dd/mm/yyyy") before inserting. When I retrieve it from the DB, I just want to display it, theres no calculation or sorting done with it so theres no need to store as a timestamp and deal with all the custom formatting I would need to display it properly. The dates show up just fine on the chart though. And while im not using stringify, i AM using json_encode() in my php code on the results retrieved from the DB. Arent those equivalents?

Comment: @Mark - Well I seem to have forgotten to try your solution, Mark to try parseInt(value.val1). Just tried it and BAM! everything works like a charm. Guess the values just weren't being set to int's properly so the chart couldn't recognize them. Thanks again to everybody who offered advice and assistance, really appreciated it! =]